# Retrieve the exact epoch at which a validator got slashed

Tags: validators

I'm currently writting a script that needs to evaluate how much money was lost due to slashing penalties by taking the balance of a validator 1 epoch before it got slashed and its balance 1 epoch before it is exited (or current balance if not yet withdrawable).

I'm currently relying on the consensus layer node api and need to not introduce any new third party.

By querying the `eth/v1/beacon/states/stateId/validators/validatorId`, I'm retrieving an object that does not provide all the information required to get the exact slashing epoch.

```
{
  "execution_optimistic": false,
  "data": {
    "index": "1",
    "balance": "1",
    "status": "active_ongoing",
    "validator": {
      "pubkey": "0x93247f2209abcacf57b75a51dafae777f9dd38bc7053d1af526f220a7489a6d3a2753e5f3e8b1cfe39b56f43611df74a",
      "withdrawal_credentials": "0xcf8e0d4e9587369b2301d0790347320302cc0943d5a1884560367e8208d920f2",
      "effective_balance": "1",
      "slashed": false,
      "activation_eligibility_epoch": "1",
      "activation_epoch": "1",
      "exit_epoch": "1",
      "withdrawable_epoch": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

What I was previously doing is use the `withdrawable_epoch` value and subtract it by `8192`, but I recently found out that this would work in most cases but not in some cases where the exit queue is too long (and where the distance between slashing epoch and withdrawable epoch is greater than 8192).

- What would be the best way to accurately find this epoch. Currently leaning towards a solution where I would start by watching at `withdrawable_epoch - 8192` and then perform a backward lookup (dichotomic search will probably do the trick) if the slashing slot is not found initialy.
- Is there some beacon api endpoint I'm missing that could give me the value I'm looking for ?